# extract several values/strings from a long string in java

Tags: java, string, extract

I need an efficient way to extract many different values/strings from a variable string

```
double A = 0;
int B = 0;
double C = 0;
String D = null;
int E = 0;
double F = 0;
String D = null;
[...]


string1 = "A=1.00;B=2;C=1.00;D=TEST;E=24;F=0.00;D=FS[...]"
string2 = "A=3.00;B=3;D=SOMESTRING;E=24;F=0.00;[..]"
string3 ="A=2.64;B=4;C=1.00;D=SOMEOTHERSTRING;E=24;D=FS[...]"
```

Is there any efficient,fast and maybe elegant way to do that ?

i tried it already with .split(";") but the if the string is variabel i have a problem!

Thanks for any ideas/help on this topic!

Comment: Time to learn about regular expressions.

Comment: What's the problem with `split`?

Comment: What do you mean "if the string is variabel"? Do you mean some of your strings may NOT be delimited by a semicolon ";"?

Comment: @tobias_k Using split is not as good as regex in this case.. there's a clear pattern.. which the values can be easily extracted from.

Comment: @MarounMaroun But then you have a bigger problem - you have to use regex :P

Comment: Is there any good decription on how to extract with regular expressions for this case? with "variabel" i mean that there could be missing some of the fields, like D in string2 or F in string3

Comment: I agree with tobias_k.  Why can you not use split?

Comment: how do i asign the values to the variables then? and what is to do when some value is missing like in string2 or 3 ?

Comment: you could use reflection (get declared fields etc) after splitting with ; and then with =.

Comment: @MarounMaroun do you have a hint for me to do it with regular expressions ? how is the general structure to extract something from the string?

Comment: @jujo you want to parse the string and then, with these values to set field A to be of value 1.00, B of value 2 etc?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I have to do that like 1 Million times, so i need an efficient way.

Comment: ok so you can use reflection. but can you have setter methods only with string and add your logic inside these methods?

Comment: Im new to Java, so i don't know anything about reflection

Comment: yes ok. but can you have all methods setters in string? setA(String value) and then handle the string to double parsing there?

Comment: Yeah i think i can do that.

Comment: i think  the regex solution will help me, i will try to solve it with that. im thankful for any regex hints!

Comment: @Jujo when you find the solution to your problem, please post it as an answer here for others to see it. it would be interesting to see how you achieved it

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you can have setter methods of string parameters, you can use reflection

```
String[] split1 = string1.split(";");
for (int i=0;i<split1.length;i++) {
  String[] insideSplit = split1[i].split("=");
  java.lang.reflect.Method method;
  try {
    method = this.getClass().getMethod("set" + insideSplit[0], String.class);
    method.invoke(this, insideSplit[1]);
  } catch (Exception e) {
  // ...
 }
}
```

then, inside your setter method, you can handle string values accordingly (to convert them to double or int or whatever you want)

Answer (score 0):

```
string1 = "A=1.00;B=2;C=1.00;D=TEST;E=24;F=0.00;D=FS[...]"

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[A][=]([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)").matcher(info);
if (matcher.find()) {
    A = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1));
}
```